# .exe Never Throws Errror

Tags: command-line, errorlevel

I am tackling what should be a VERY simple solution to a problem.  In short, I am calling WinSCP.com, to SFTP files as:

```
WinSCP.com /nointeractiveinput /command "open sftp://!Username!:!Password!@!Host! -hostkey="*"" "put !FolderName! !EgressPath!" "exit" >>MasterLog.txt

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo ERROR: SFTP error on folder: !FolderName!>>MasterLog.txt
    exit
)
```

However, during integration testing, with or without passing the output to MasterLog.txt, this program literally NEVER throws an error, even dropping parameters, fake passwords. etc.

I feel like I am going crazy as almost all .exe when called from command line will fail occassionally and throw an error that is not "0", this ALWAYS returns "0"...no matter what

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Remove the `%` around ERRORLEVEL. It's not an environmental variable.

Comment: @KenWhite, according to documentation, it is referenced that way: https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html

Comment: @KenWhite, what looks like what worked was setting to `!ERRORLEVEL!`,

Comment: Not according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc754335%28v%3dws.11%29)